# Automator find array of names in find finder items

Tags: applescript, automator, finder

Hello I am trying to find a bunch of files all with different names in automator.

I have find finder items set up to find names that contains "rooms"

this only selects 1 file.

The problem is I have a list of specific names and instead of adding many conditions and pasting each name in separately, I was wondering if theres a way to make an array and list all of the names there?

I tried adding a comma to separate each name but it reads it as a large string.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to filter partial strings in a list of names you need a repeat loop.

Answer (score 1):

I have made an Applescript that you can add after the Find Finder Items action and the Script will return a LIST of file paths found:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set noFilesInputed to the number of items of input
    set fileList to {}
    if noFilesInputed is greater than 0 then
        repeat with cFile from 1 to noFilesInputed
            set cFileItem to item cFile of input
            set cFilePath to cFileItem as string
            set fileList to fileList & {cFilePath}
        end repeat
    end if
    return fileList
end run
```

If the number of inputed items is 0 then
the list outputed is empty

Hope this helps!